# Permission denied on mkdir inside of a django Docker container when running collectstatic

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, cookiecutter-django, caddy

I've modified django-cookiecutter default production template to make **caddy** web server serve static files. I'm using volumes to map the `./static` directories in **django** and **caddy** containters through host `./static` directory, but I'm getting permissions error when docker executes `python manage.py collectstatic --noinput` while trying to create a subfolder of `./static`.

However, if I don't switch to `django` user in django container's Dockerfile, hence execute `collectstatic` as root, everything works perfectly. I guess `django` user in the container is not allowed to write to host directory, even despite the fact that `chown -R django /app/static` was successfully executed.

> Traceback (most recent call last): 
>   File "/app/manage.py", line 30, in <\module> 
>   execute_from_command_line(sys.argv) 
>   ... 
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/collectfast/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 111, in copy_file 
>   self.do_copy_file(args) 
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/collectfast/management/commands/collectstatic.py",
>   line 100, in do_copy_file 
>   path, prefixed_path, source_storage) 
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 354, in copy_file 
>  
>   self.storage.save(prefixed_path, source_file) 
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py",
>   line 49, in save 
>   return self._save(name, content) 
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 236, in _save 
>   os.makedirs(directory) 
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 220, in makedirs 
>   mkdir(name, mode) 
>   PermissionError: 
>   [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/app/static/sass'

I tried `chown -R systemd-timesync:root static` inside host, creating `./static` folder beforehand inside host as root, and adding `RUN mkdir /app/static && chown -R django /app/static` to django container's Dockerfile (to execute as container's root user).

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  production_postgres_data: {}
  production_postgres_data_backups: {}
  production_caddy: {}

services:
  django:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/django/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./static:/app/static
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.production/.django
      - ./.envs/.production/.postgres
    command: /start

  postgres:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/postgres/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - production_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - production_postgres_data_backups:/backups
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.production/.postgres

  caddy:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/caddy/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - django
    volumes:
      - production_caddy:/root/.caddy
      - ./static:/srv/static
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.production/.caddy
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:80:80"
      - "0.0.0.0:443:443"

  redis:
    image: redis:3.2
```

django container Dockerfile

```
FROM nickgryg/alpine-pandas

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apk update \
  # psycopg2 dependencies
  && apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev \
  && apk add postgresql-dev \
  # Pillow dependencies
  && apk add jpeg-dev zlib-dev freetype-dev lcms2-dev openjpeg-dev tiff-dev tk-dev tcl-dev \
  # CFFI dependencies
  && apk add libffi-dev py-cffi \
  # lxml dependencies
  && apk add libxml2-dev libxslt-dev

RUN addgroup -S django \
    && adduser -S -G django django

# Requirements are installed here to ensure they will be cached.
COPY ./requirements /requirements
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /requirements/production.txt \
    && rm -rf /requirements

COPY ./compose/production/django/entrypoint /entrypoint
RUN sed -i 's/\r//' /entrypoint
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint
RUN chown django /entrypoint

COPY ./compose/production/django/start /start
RUN sed -i 's/\r//' /start
RUN chmod +x /start
RUN chown django /start

COPY . /app

RUN chown -R django /app

USER django

WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint"]
```

django container start script

```
#!/bin/sh

set -o errexit
set -o pipefail
set -o nounset

python /app/manage.py collectstatic --noinput
/usr/local/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 --chdir=/app
```

I don't want my container to be executed as root, so I'm looking for any solutions / ideas.

Comment: Are you using Whitenoise or not? How are you settings for static files? The ones in the prod config here: https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django/blob/e97304387d26c7d6dab0bba45f5c3426983e44dd/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.project_slug%7D%7D/config/settings/production.py#L78-L83

Comment: @BrunoA. no, I'm not, thanks for the insight, I will consider using it! I forked from cookiecutter before Whitenoise was added, so I just replaced AWS lines with local static folder, and then serve them with caddy webserver by using "except /static"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found a workaround other than executing `collectstatic` as `root`. 
As I suspected, the problem was in docker's permissions, and we should grant Docker the permissions to create folders in /static folder, which is owned by `django` user inside django Docker container. We can do that, knowing that `userId` is the same between host system and the container, by running

```
docker-compose run django id -u django
```

It outputs the `userId` of the `django` user in the system. For instance, `uid` is `100`. Then run (not sure about `gid`, but it works when `gid` = `uid` + 1)

```
chown -R 100:101 /static
```

If we run `ls -lh`, we can see that `static` folder is owned by `systemd-network`, which is sort of a Docker user mapped to `uid = 100`

```
drwxr-xr-x  4 root            root            4.0K Sep 27 11:23 compose
drwxr-xr-x  3 root            root            4.0K Nov 27 12:09 config
drwxr-xr-x  3 root            root            4.0K Nov 14 02:04 docs
drwxr-xr-x  2 root            root            4.0K Sep 27 11:23 locale
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root            root            1.1K Sep 27 12:56 manage.py
...
drwxr-xr-x 11 systemd-network systemd-journal 4.0K Nov 21 22:15 static
drwxr-xr-x  2 root            root            4.0K Nov 27 13:37 utils
```

It should solve the problem. Beware that after rebuilding the container `uid` of `django` user may change, and the error will appear again, so you would have to repeat this.

Everyone who understands a bit more how Docker works is welcome to explain what happens here, and I will accept his answer.

Comment: This fix unfortunately does not work if your application model(s) contain file fields, since every file uploaded will also have root as the owner